Switch off UEFI Secure Boot and lose saved keys?
I want to switch off Secure Boot which is set in User/Custom mode on Lenovo L15 gen.2, currently running Windows 11; I want to disable it and swap an Nvme disk to run Windows 10 without Secure Boot.
Will disabling Secure Boot delete custom keys that are needed for currently running Windows 11, or will it just be disabled, then when enabling again (before inserting back the Win11 nVME), all will be fine with custom keys still present (I would like to avoid situation in which I can't boot Windows 11)?
Are there any other precausions to take to be on the safe side?


Seems like an X-Y Problem - what's the reason for disabling Secure Boot? Secure Boot's purpose is to prevent malware from being injected into the bootloader

No X-Y. It's only X. I want to disable Secure Boot for whatever reason for the other OS.

By Custom Keys do you mean the Windows UEFI CA 2023 or you have inserted your own certificates into the 'db'?

Since Secure Boot is in Custom/User mode, I believe own certificates might be inserted in database for Windows 11. And that's what I mean not to loose.

@rajeev My mistake, that was directed at the OP =]

@Kamil What other OS? All OSes support Secure Boot AFAIK (all modern Windows editions do, as it's been a requirement for OEMs by Microsoft since Win 8)

@rajeev I mentioned two OSs: Windows 10 and Windows 11 so by "the other one" I meant obviously Windows 10 as in my post.
